# PL/SQL If rows found do this; otherwise do something else

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a procedure in pl/sql which will tell me who has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE privileges on all application tables in the Oracle database.

Either:

1. A user has no privileges on the table
2. A user has privileges on the table based on a direct grant like "grant select on table_ABC to user_123"
3. A user has privileges on the table based on a granted role like "grant read_only_role to user_123" where read_only_role contains "grant select on table_ABC to read_only_role"
4. A user has privileges on the table based on a system privilege like SELECT ANY TABLE
5. A user has privileges on the table based on a role like DBA which contains SELECT ANY TABLE.

Now, I face no errors creating a procedure with #2 (for example) when I hard-code the users or table names.  But when I try to create 1 procedure which includes all these scenarios, I run into a problem when DATA_NOT_FOUND.

I can handle the exception, but the procedure exits afterwards.  I am not able to make the code run regardless of whether data is found.  SQL%NOTFOUND is not working for me, as the DATA_NOT_FOUND exception is raised before the code with SQL%NOTFOUND is executed.

What I want to happen is:

1. The procedure loops through all the application tables
2. The procedure loops through all the users
3. If there is a direct grant, variable1 = 'TRUE' or the same thing is done using SELECT INTO
4. If there is a role grant, variable2 = 'TRUE' or the same thing is done using SELECT INTO
5. If there is a system privilege grant, variable3 = 'TRUE' or the same thing is done using SELECT INTO
6. If there is a DBA role grant, variable4 = 'TRUE' or the same thing is done using SELECT INTO
7. The procedure prints Table Name, Username, Yes/No for each of the items above.

How can I modify the code so that if User_123 has the SELECT privilege on Table_ABC, then variable1 = 'TRUE', otherwise variable1 = 'FALSE'?  The DATA_NOT_FOUND exception should not be raised if there is no record for User_123 in dba_tab_privs.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

```
DECLARE
  by_tab_priv varchar(20);

BEGIN

  dbms_output.enable(1000000);

  FOR x IN ( SELECT table_name
           FROM dba_tables
           WHERE owner IN ('NIKUP')
           ORDER BY table_name )
  LOOP

    BEGIN

      FOR y IN ( SELECT username from dba_users
           ORDER BY username)
      LOOP


        SELECT grantee 
        INTO by_tab_priv 
        FROM dba_tab_privs 
        WHERE    grantee=y.username 
             and table_name=x.table_name 
             and privilege in ('SELECT')
        MINUS
        SELECT granted_role 
        FROM dba_role_privs 
        WHERE granted_role in (
                SELECT grantee 
                FROM dba_tab_privs 
                WHERE     grantee=y.username 
                      and table_name=x.table_name 
                      and privilege in ('SELECT'));

        BEGIN
          dbms_output.put_line(y.username || ' ' || by_tab_priv);
        END;

       END LOOP;
     END;
   END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      by_tab_priv:='FALSE';
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
begin
  select ... into ;
  var1 :=TRUE;
exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then  -- controlling the case with no_data_found
    var1 := FAlSE;
```

### end;

**UPDATE**

```
  LOOP
   BEGIN
    SELECT grantee 
    INTO by_tab_priv 
    FROM dba_tab_privs 
    WHERE    grantee=y.username 
         and table_name=x.table_name 
         and privilege in ('SELECT')
    MINUS
    SELECT granted_role 
    FROM dba_role_privs 
    WHERE granted_role in (
            SELECT grantee 
            FROM dba_tab_privs 
            WHERE     grantee=y.username 
                  and table_name=x.table_name 
                  and privilege in ('SELECT'));


    dbms_output.put_line(y.username || ' ' || by_tab_priv);

   EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     by_tab_priv:='FALSE';
   END;

 END LOOP;
```

the exception is linked only to the block inside the loop, it is not a global exception

A block has a structure like:

```
BEGIN
EXCEPTION 
END
```

and you can have multiple blocks inside a function , with every block doing it's own handling of exceptions.

Comment: I tried to implement this solution using the code above.  This is only a first attempt which I will later perfect, but the same thing is happening.  The procedure executes successfully, but that's only because when no_data_found, it exits.

Comment: no, the exception is used as flow control, if data_found (select ... into) then do_something else_if not_data_found then do_something_else.

Comment: For some of the usernames, there is data in dba_tab_privs.  For others, there is not.  How do I make it return to the loop and continue processing records after it enters the exception block?  Can I put a GOTO statement  inside the exception block?

Comment: Thank you very much valentin.  I am also rewriting my query.  I will post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

use the following trick to avoid the exception

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(grantee), 'FALSE')
INTO by_tab_priv
FROM (
  SELECT
  ...
  MINUS
  SELECT
  ...
)
```

alternatively you can use `SIGN(COUNT(grantee))`, which returns `1` or `0`

Comment: Thank you very much Pavel.  Both solutions work.  Also select count(*) into var1 and then using if/else logic works if I want to keep a record of the  count, in cases where a user has been granted 2+ roles which have overlapping privileges.

Comment: If a SELECT INTO statement fails to return a row, PL/SQL raises the predefined exception NO_DATA_FOUND whether you check SQL%NOTFOUND on the next line or not. However, a SELECT INTO statement that calls a SQL aggregate function never raises NO_DATA_FOUND because those functions always return a value or a null. In such cases, SQL%NOTFOUND yields FALSE.